# Подскажите программы для отправки POST/GET данных

Tags: json, postman

Использую **Postman** в работе, но в последнее время требуется отправлять не просто объектные **json-данные**, а файлы. И вот тут у меня **Postman** стал капризничать: не хочет отправлять файлы.

Вроде как все по инструкции делаю:

[image: Вроде как все по инструкции делаю:]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но после отправки вот такой сюрприз (не отправляет файл):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Поэтому решил плюнуть уже на него (т.к. чтение документации не помогает) и решил использовать другое средство для отправки **json-данных**.

Кто какие средства использует? Хочу сменить инструмент.

Comment: `и решил использовать другое средство для отправки json-данных.` - так вам бинарный файл нужно отправлять или JSON? в JSON просто так бинарные данные не вставишь, только в конвертированном в текст виде, в BASE64, например.

Comment: Еще, `Content-Length: "19527"` как бы намекает, что запрос не пустой пришел, возможно просто консоль не умеет бинарные данные отображать. Ну и я бы на самом сервере еще проверил, пришли данные или нет.

Comment: @insolor, я раньше отправлял точно также (этот же файл) - все приходило и отправляло. Видимо какое-то обновление прошло и теперь не отправляет. Фишка в том еще, что он даже ключ **imgFile** не видит. А если указать не файл, а текстовые данные - то и ключ видит и данные отправляет

Comment: Я использую `curl` - еще не подводил. Но это command line - так что на любителя. Чтоб точно проверить, что посылает postman используйте netcat. Запускаете `nc -l 5000` и посылайте запрос вместо своего сервера, на `localhost:5000`, netcat покажет все что пришло.

Comment: @Roman Konoval, после команды **nc -l 5000** Вышло **local listen fuxored: INVAL**. Отправил POST-запрос на адрес **http://127.0.0.1:5000/test_adr** - в консоли ничего нет, а **Postman** отправил ключи и значение из формы только содержащие строковый тип данных, а ключи и файлы - не отправил

Comment: Я обычно использую postman, расширение thunder client в vscode (прямой аналог postman) или python + request.

Comment: На windows у netcat чуть [другие параметры](https://github.com/diegocr/netcat/issues/5): `nc -L -p 5000`

Comment: @Roman Konoval, тоже глухо